# Updating relationships in laravel - OneToMany & ManyToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Suppose I have a 'Post' model & a 'Comment' model. **A 'Post' can have multiple 'Comments'**.

Suppose, **I allow user to add/edit/delete multiple comments & 'submit' in a single form**.

Now, *as the user submits all the comments*, some of them might have been edited, some not, some might have been deleted & some added. In such case, what *I currently do* is - *'delete all the existing comments for that post & add all the submitted comments (no matter if they were edited/added) again'*.

This led me into a **problem - The autoincrement 'id' field of the 'comments' table started taking big values (even when the total number of comments is not equal to its value).**

**Solution I see is - Update the existing comments first & add more comments if they are actually added.**

So my question is - Is there a way in laravel to update in such a scenario? For ex. -

```
$post->comments()->update(array($comment1,$comment2));
```

where

```
$comment1 = array('comment_heading' => 'new/edited heading for comment',
'comment_content' => 'some new/edited content for comment');
```

where
'comment_heading' , 'comment_content' are columns of the 'comment' table.

Also, this case talks about 'oneToMany' relationship but an additional solution on 'ManyToMany' relationship would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The autoincrement 'id' field of the 'comments' table started taking big value" - as long as the field has an appropriate type, I can't see this ever being an issue

Comment: @rjdown will keeping it to 'bigInt' always going to save me from any problem?

Comment: Well, unsigned standard int can go up to nearly 4.3 billion... if you don't think that's enough (!) then sure, go with bigint.